# REST API URL pattern design for GET request

Tags: c#, rest, api, naming-conventions

I am currently developing a REST API for GET request.

I am developing an API that returns sponosred ads for application, category and platform say e.g. application is google, platform is mobilesite and category is homepage banner, and an API that returns ads based on above inputs.
I can have multiple category for same application and same category can exist in any application or platform.
I can not be sure how to configure the URLpattern to be correct.

Please advise me of a good URL pattern.

I am considering the options below.

1. api/sponsored/{applicationId}/{category}/?platformId=1
2. api/sponsored/{category}/{applicationId}/?platformId=1

where category is a string e.g. wallpaper, banner etc

Comment: Why that query string? You need to think for yourself what belongs to who, but both URLs seem wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, my URI's for a REST API would be something like

- /api/application/{id} <- returns (GET), creates (POST, PUT), updates
  (PUT) an application object
- /api/category/{id}
- /api/platform/{id}

Where each object has a unique URI.

If I was to use REST to access and create specific ads, it might look like

- /api/ad/{id} <- returns (GET), creates (POST, PUT), updates
  (PUT) an ad object
- /api/ad/ <- return all ads (GET)
- **/api/ad?application={applicationId}&category={categoryId}&platform={platformId} <- query/filter ads (GET)**

One can use RPC rather than REST, which is sometimes more efficient/simpler, particularly if you want to return "joined" data. For example:

- **/rpc/GetAds?application={applicationId}&category={categoryId}&platform={platformId}**
- /rpc/GetAds?a={applicationId}&c={categoryId}&p={platformId} <- less network traffic

Everything doesn't have to be RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better pass the values as query strings which is something we usually do with search, filter or sort operations. so you don't worry about the order

```
api/sponsored?category=1&applicationId=2&platformId=1
```

Comment: category is string

Comment: you can put string value instead of number based on the application needs.
    api/sponsored?category={category}&applicationId={applicationId}&platformId={platformId}